# Which Freeware "GUI tool" for "Firebird RDBMS" closestly resembles "MS SQL Server 2000 Management Studio"?

Tags: firebird

Which Freeware "GUI tool" for "Firebird RDBMS" closestly resembles "MS SQL Server 2000 Management Studio"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[EMS](http://sqlmanager.net/fr/products/ibfb/manager/download), [Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com/downloads.php#dbw) and [IBExpert](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/) have lite version

My favourite is IBExpert

Comment: you can set your code page in Windows to WIN1251

Comment: @hellboy:  chcp 1251, hahaha, that's a good one ;)

Comment: @Quandary use Cyrillic to feel free!

Answer (score 15):

Use FlameRobin, the best Firebird GUI (AFAIK), written in C++ & wxWidgets (=Cross-Platform).

http://www.flamerobin.org/

Comment: There is nothing "official" about FlameRobin. 

https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/qsg3/firebird-3-quickstartguide.html#qsg3-config-admintools

Comment: @The incredible Jan; Fine, you're right - changed that. But it ships with Ubuntu's default-repositories ;)

Answer (score 6):

The best freeware GUI tool for FireBird is this:
[EMS SQL Manager for InterBase/Firebird](http://sqlmanager.net/en/products/ibfb/manager)

They have a freeware version which you can download from here:
[Download Freeware version of EMS SQL Manager](http://sqlmanager.net/en/products/ibfb/manager/download)

Answer (score 4):

I love [IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.com/). I know, it's not freeware. Just wanted to mentioned it.

You can go with one Java based tool like Oracle's [SQLDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html), Eclipse's [SQLExplorer](http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/) or [SQUIRREL-SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/). Of course, for all these tools, you will need [Firebird's JDBC driver](http://firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=devel&sub=jdbc&id=faq). And a little bit of Java knowledge to setup your connections.

Answer (score 3):

[SQL Maestro Group](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/) offers AnySQL Maestro (a freeware tool for all DBMS accessible via OLE DB/ODBC). They also have Firebird Maestro, but it is a shareware.

Comment: I've been using Firebird Maestro for more than a year now. So far it's my favorite.

Answer (score 2):

I like http://www.sql-workbench.net

Java based, cross-platform and free.

Answer (score 1):

I use [IBOConsole](http://www.mengoni.it/Downloads/) (it has done the job for me so far)

Answer (score -3):

utility fbmetadata You can find it on Softpedia
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Database-Utils/Utility-FBMetaData.shtml

Comment: Welcome to SO... posting LinkOnly answers is generally frowned-upon.  Please consider elaborating on your answer